# Can a chrome extension that only has site access "on click" still see your browsing history other times?

Tags: google-chrome, permissions, google-chrome-extensions, privacy, privacy-extensions

If I have a chrome extension that only gets site access "On click", but also has other permissions, is still active in the background without my clicking?

Can it access my browsing history all of the time?

Bonus: If so, what can I do about this to have extensions I only want to give permissions in specific circumstances (ideally even limited by domain/session).
[image: Example]